# How Can I use Datatables DeferRender with gridview databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatables

my Problem Is when I use `Databind` to Populate data to `Gridview` with large amount of data (more than 2k rows) It's cause a lot of time (5 - 10 Sec) and shown all row before wrapping to paging

I found that `datatables` option for Ajax is `deferrender` and I think its can solve my problem, but I can't use it with `databind` I try to use but nothing possible

**GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                            EnableViewState="false"
                            CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered jambo_table  dt-responsive nowrap" Width="100%" CellSpacing="0"
                            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
 HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="50px" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TERM" HeaderText="Terminal" SortExpression="TERM">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="150px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LOCATION" HeaderText="Location">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="RESPONSE" HeaderText="Response">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="EMV_FLAG" HeaderText="POS_ENTRY">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TOTAL" HeaderText="Total"
                                    SortExpression="TOTAL">
                                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100px" />
                                </asp:BoundField>
                            </Columns>
                            <RowStyle CssClass="rowStyle" />

                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerStyle" />
                            <FooterStyle CssClass="footerStyle" />
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>

                        </asp:GridView>
```

**Datatables**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %>').GridviewFix({
                header: "headerStyle",
                row: "rowStyle",
                footer: "footerStyle"
            }).dataTable({
                dom: "Bfrtip",
                paging: true
      , buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: "copy",
                        className: "btn-sm",
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, ':visible']
                        }
                    },
                  {
                      extend: "csv",
                      className: "btn-sm",
                      title: "Cash",
                      exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':visible'
                      }

                  },
                  {
                      extend: "excelHtml5",
                      className: "btn-sm",
                      exportOptions: {
                          columns: ':visible'
                      },
                      title: "Cash",
                  },
                  {
                      extend: "pdfHtml5",
                      className: "btn-sm",
                      title: "Cash",
                      orientation: 'landscape',
                      pageSize: 'A3'
                  },
                  {
                      extend: "print",
                      className: "btn-sm",
                      title: "Cash Status ",
                  },

      ],
                columnDefs: [
          {
              targets: 0,
              visible: false
          }
                ],
                responsive: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this post. It might help solving the issue. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/grid-view-with-lazy-load-binding-and-custom-pagination1

Comment: datatables is a jquery plug-in, there are some examples which are very helpful, here is the link https://datatables.net/

Comment: @din I know there some examples which very helpful, but not for gridview. Thank you

Comment: @kami your post are not compatible much to use with datatables, I've tried.